# Mongoose - Model.create

Tags: mongoose

I am trying to create a new document in a collection using mongoose.
I execute the following code:

```
const doc = await m.create(req.body); //m is the model
```

After sending the request using postman I receive the following error message:
"E11000 duplicate key error collection: myDB.objects index: name_1 dup key: { name: null }"

- my DB contains just a doc without any null value

Could you help me, please?

Comment: Looks like you have an indexed property name in your model. can you add your schema?

Comment: @ISAE Yes, I have. However, I use all of them while creating the doc in the req.body.
The schema is:

const prodSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   name: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'An product must have a name'], 
    unique: true,
  }
  price: {
    type: Number,
    required: [true, 'A product must have a price'],
  },

Comment: console.log your req.body, make sure all required properties are in there. this error code is trying to tell you that you already have a doc in your collection with the same value for name - that value somehow being null. now when you try to create another doc with same value it gives you duplicate key error.

Comment: @ISAE Thank you for your help.
I deleted every document in my database. Then, I tried filling it with new docs. The first one is always created, successfully. 
In the second one, I change each value of all the properties. However, I still receive the same error. It's so weird.

Comment: As I suggested above, try to `console.log(req.body)` just before doing `create()`, and carefully inspect those values. It strongly sounds to me that for some reason you are not getting the values correctly there.

Comment: @ISAE thanks a lot!
I found out the cause.. even though, I was deleting the docs off my collection, each id I had defined before was not deleted from the Atlas mongoDB (so I could not store as you mention again the same data)